# Node osrm setup failure

Tags: linux, node.js, makefile, installation, osrm

I have installed node osrm using `npm install osrm` on Ubuntu 14.04. This has installed the OSRM v4.9. The next step is to setup OSRM. I am trying to follow the steps given in the wiki for setup-
https://github.com/Project-OSRM/node-osrm

When I run `make` I get the below errors

```
/bin/sh: 1: [[: not found
/bin/sh: 1: echo you need pkg-config installed: not found
make: *** [pkgconfig] Error 127
```

When I run `./Makefile`, I get the below errors

```
./Makefile: line 3: shell: command not found
./Makefile: line 3: TOOL_ROOT?=/lib/binding: No such file or directory
./Makefile: line 4: TOOL_ROOT: command not found
```

I even added a shebang to use bash since the errors seem to be due to non usage of bash

I have installed all the required libraries and have node v0.12

How can I run the https://github.com/Project-OSRM/node-osrm/blob/develop/Makefile file successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on macos. I figured out that pkg-config is needed to be installed. Try to install it running **sudo apt-get install pkg-config**